# is it possible to add x_ticks to pywaffle

Tags: python, matplotlib

i was wondering if and how i can add x axis label to pywaffle.

```
value1 = new_df['value1'].tolist() 
new_list = [i+1 for i in range(len(value1))]   

fig = plt.figure(
    FigureClass=Waffle,
    rows=1,
    columns=len(value1),  # Either rows or columns could be omitted
    values=value1, 
    title = {"label": name, "loc": "left"},

)

plt.savefig("plot.png", bbox_inches="tight")
```

my value1 values are [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]

i will like every column to be labeld

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to add ticks etc.

## A waffle chart with limited number of columns

But it is a bit unclear what your final goal is.  By default, a waffle charts draws as many squares as each of the values indicates.  So, if the values are `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, and the color `['red', 'orange', 'blue', 'gold', 'green', 'purple']`, there would be 1 red square, 2 oranges, 3 blues, 4 yellows, 5 greens and 6 purples.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pywaffle import Waffle

value1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
fig = plt.figure(
    FigureClass=Waffle,
    rows=1,
    #columns=sum(value1),
    values=value1,
    colors=['red','orange','blue','gold','green','purple']
)
```

[image: waffle chart without limiting the columns]

If you set the number of `rows` and `columns` so their product is smaller than 21, each of the values will be reduced more or less proportionally, but still be an integer. In the current example, the red one goes suppressed, the orange, blue, yellow and green get reduced to 1, and the green gets reduced to 2 squares.  This makes it unclear which label you want to put where.

```
value1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
fig = plt.figure(
    FigureClass=Waffle,
    rows=1,
    columns=len(value1),
    values=value1,
    colors=['red','orange','blue','gold','green','purple']
)
```

[image: waffle chart limiting the number of columns]

## Adding x ticks

To add ticks to a waffle chart, you can turn the axes on. To position the ticks, you need to know that the squares have a width of `1`, and a default distance of `0.2`. So, the first tick comes at `0.5`, the next one at `1+0.2+0.5`, etc. Optionally, you can remove spines and the dummy y ticks.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pywaffle import Waffle

value1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]
fig = plt.figure(
    FigureClass=Waffle,
    rows=1,
    columns=len(value1),
    values=value1,
    title={"label": 'title', "loc": "left"},
    figsize=(15,3),
)
plt.axis('on')
plt.yticks([])
plt.xticks([i * 1.2 + 0.5 for i in range(len(value1))], value1)
for sp in ['left', 'right', 'top']:
    plt.gca().spines[sp].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image: waffle chart with x ticks]

## A Seaborn heatmap

Instead of a waffle chart, you could create a heatmap. Then, each square will get a color corresponding to the given values. Optionally, these values (or another string) can be shown as annotation or as x tick label.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

value1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 3))
ax = sns.heatmap(data=[value1], xticklabels=value1, yticklabels=False,
                 annot=True, square=True, linewidths=1.5, cbar=False)
ax.set_title('title', loc='left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn heatmap from one row]

Answer (score 0):

```
# Remove borders, ticks, etc.
        ax.axis("off")
```

saw this in pywaffle.py, so i dont think adding axis is possible.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).